# Why is my scroll not working with my anchors?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've dragged the code from here; http://www.mymcreative.com/

For a site's skeleton:
http://soniahsieh.com/dev/index2.html

But for some reason the jQuery scroll is dead? I can't determine why?

Anybody know?

Comment: what do you mean by dead? whats it doing, what is it meant to do? what errors are you getting etc etc etc.

Comment: I can't see any parallax scroll at http://www.mymcreative.com/ as well

Comment: It's not smooth scrolling as the referenced URL I dragged from. The links just act as html anchors.

Comment: That's not a parallax effect.

Comment: Smooth Scroll -- sorry. Anchors links that transition smoothly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see a couple of issues

1. As pointed out by Jashwant the jQuery.anchor.js file throws an error. You are linking to the file directly at http://www.mymcreative.com/js/jquery.anchor.js which is never a good idea. Also it isn't downloading the file correctly, if you view the source it is full of HTML instead of the JavaScript you see if you browse to that file in your browser. Download a copy of the file and upload it to your web server then reference the copy on your web server
2. Your a tags don't link to an id on your site, for example you have this `<a href="#topReception"</a>` but you don't have an element with the id of "topReception" on your site. Well you do but it is commented out at the bottom of the page as I presume you copied the HTML from the mymcreative site too?

Answer (score 0):

Your `jQuery.anchor.js` throws an error **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token *** .

You have not commented the code properly at the top.

Use `/*   */` for multiline comment

and `//` for single line comment.

Answer (score 0):

You're scripts are'nt loaded because of several errors and typos, start on this line:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content'"text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Where there's an extra quote after content, basically puting much of your head section inside the `content=""` declaration, and work your way down until all the typos are fixed.

There are also some issues in some external JS files, as pointed out by Jashwant.

Comment: your `declaration` as a typo too ;)